# Is there a test that can tell me, even for low counts, the probability that the obtained distribution of values eg from a die is truly random?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance

The background is that I have data and a number of independent variables. For each variable I want to ascertain the probability that the distribution of that variable's values is random for that data.

For example, suppose I have a variable X, and I have a distribution of the possible values of X like this:

```
X=1 : 5 events
X=2 : 0 events
X=3 : 5 events
```

Intuitively, it's clear that this is not a random distribution. Is there a test I can perform that gives me the probability that this distribution is random? (So for this particular example, I would guess pretty low like 0.1% or something)?

Ultimately I want to be able to compare the different variables by this probability to calculate which variable has the lowest probability of being truly random.

Also, I'm not a statistician/mathematician so apologies for any terminology mistakes.

Many thanks!

Comment: Using a chi-square statistic suggests your example may have a $p$-value of around $0.08$ rather than your guessed $0.001$.  This is not "the probability that this distribution is random", but an approximation to the probability of seeing this result or something as or more extreme if the distribution is in fact uniform.

Comment: Every probability distribution is random, what do you mean by “truly random”? Do you want to test if the values come from a uniform distribution? Or maybe you want to test the pseudo-random number generator if it produces outputs nondistinguishable from random values?

Comment: Standard statistical hypothesis tests do *not* give you a probability that there is a certain "true" distribution (for example uniform if this is what you mean by "random"). Rather they could reject such a hypothesis based on a low probability for your result *assuming* such a distribution as true. If you want a probability that the true underlying distribution is uniform (or something else), you need a Bayesian approach, which would require you to specify prior probabilities for your hypothesis and also for alternative distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Test for goodness of fit with categorical data, whether a particular distribution is a good fit for a particular sample, are the [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) and the [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test).

Note that those tests are testing the assumption that an experimental outcome follows a *particular* distribution. For instance whether a particular die has equal probability to roll 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. These two tests do not test whether the result is 'random' in general. A [test for randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test) is practically impossible because randomness can be violated in infinitely many ways.